# phonegap plugin barcodescanner not working on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, barcode-scanner

We are developing application for phonegap (2.4.0) - iOS (6) and Android platforms. Our app is using BarcodeScanner plugin. 
Plugin is working without any problems on Android, but we have detected some problems on iOS.

At first in the file CDVBarcodeScanner.mm CDVPlugin.h was not found, so we commented if/else check around this line: `#import <CORDOVA/CDVPlugin.h>` and to config.xml file we have added this line: `<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner" value="CDVBarcodeScanner" />`
Then was build successfull without any errors, but after clicking on scan button nothing happened and nothing was written to output.

Then we compared barcodescanner.js for Android and iOS and found that after adding logs at the end of Android js file:

```
if(!window.plugins) {
    console.log("something 1");
    window.plugins = {};
}
if (!window.plugins.barcodeScanner) {
    window.plugins.barcodeScanner = new BarcodeScanner();
    console.log("something 2");
}
```

output was written after starting of application. In the case of iOS we have also added to similar part some console logs:

```
(function() {
   if (!window.plugins) window.plugins = {}
   console.log("something 1");
   if (!window.plugins.barcodeScanner) {
        window.plugins.barcodeScanner = new BarcodeScanner();
        console.log("something 2");
   }
   else {
        console.log("Not installing barcodeScanner: window.plugins.barcodeScanner already exists")
   }
})
```

but no one was written.

Thanks for every advice.

Comment: +1 Can I ask if your IOS application was developed in Windows OS?

Comment: iOS app was developed under Mac

Comment: can it be done in Windows OS Eclipse?

Comment: I read that it can be possible, but I think that it will be long long way to find a lot of information how to do it... Easiest way is to develop on Mac :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info @matej148 :) You are being helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tried these changes and plugin works:

1. we downgraded to phonegap 2.3
2. we set -O0 compile flags to zxing-all-in-one.cpp
3. checked all added libraries